# preview image function causing FileUpload control to reset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image, file-upload, preview

code snippet for my image upload:

```
'Read the file and convert it to Byte Array
 Dim filePath As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
 Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
 Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(filename)
 Dim contenttype As String = String.Empty

 'Set the contenttype based on File Extension
 Select Case ext
      Case ".jpg"
           contenttype = "image/jpg"
           Exit Select
      Case ".png"
           contenttype = "image/png"
           Exit Select
 End Select

If Not contenttype Is String.Empty Then

 Dim fs As Stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream
 Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
 Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)

 'insert the file into database
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@imgName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@contentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = contenttype
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes

Else

 cmd.Parameters.Add("@imgName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@contentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = DBNull.Value

End If

con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
con.Close()
```

preview image:

```
Protected Sub preview_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles preview_btn.Click
    Session("ImageBytes") = FileUpload1.FileBytes
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx"

    preview_btn.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Lime
    preview_btn.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White

    Image1.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Lime
End Sub
```

Handler1.ashx

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="VB" Class="Handler1" %>

Imports System
Imports System.Web

Public Class Handler1 : Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState

Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    If (context.Session("ImageBytes")) IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim image As Byte() = DirectCast(context.Session("ImageBytes"), Byte())
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(image)
    End If
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() As Boolean Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
    Get
        Return False
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```

The preview image works but whenever I invoke the preview image button, the `FileUpload` control get reset.

So from the `FileUpload` control's point of view, it is as if the user did not select any image in the first place.

I tried storing the value of `FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName` in some variable first and then manually set back its value but `FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName` appears to be read-only, which makes sense from a security perspective.

So workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick solution, I would do the following:

1. **Preview** - Save the posted file in session. Set the Image1 image url to handler.
2. **Handler** - Get the posted file from session. Write image to response.
3. **Upload** - Check if file exists in FileUpload1, get it. If not, get it
   from session. Save image. Clear session.

Here's the code I would use:

**EDIT : Changed the code to fix issue with larger (> 50kb) images**

**aspx.vb**

```
Protected Sub btnUpload_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
    'Disabled DB operations for test
    'Read the file and convert it to Byte Array
    Dim filePath As String = String.Empty
    Dim filename As String = String.Empty
    Dim ext As String = String.Empty
    Dim contenttype As String = String.Empty
    Dim bytes As Byte()

    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
    Else
        If (Session("MyFile") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Session("MyFileName") IsNot Nothing) Then
            filePath = Session("MyFileName").ToString()
            bytes = DirectCast(Session("MyFile"), Byte())
        End If
    End If

    filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
    ext = Path.GetExtension(filename)

    'Set the contenttype based on File Extension
    Select Case ext
        Case ".jpg"
            contenttype = "image/jpg"
            Exit Select
        Case ".png"
            contenttype = "image/png"
            Exit Select
    End Select

    If Not contenttype Is String.Empty Then
        If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
            Dim fs As Stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream
            Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)
        End If
        'insert the file into database
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@imgName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@contentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = contenttype
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes

    Else

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@imgName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@contentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = DBNull.Value
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = DBNull.Value

    End If

    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

    'Cleanup
    Session("MyFile") = Nothing
    Session("MyFileName") = Nothing
End Sub

Protected Sub preview_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles preview_btn.Click
    If FileUpload1.PostedFile IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim file As HttpPostedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile

        Dim data As Byte() = New [Byte](file.ContentLength - 1) {}
        file.InputStream.Read(data, 0, file.ContentLength)

        Session("MyFile") = data
        Session("MyFileName") = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/Handler1.ashx"

        preview_btn.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Lime
        preview_btn.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.White

        Image1.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.Lime
    End If
End Sub
```

**Handler1.ashx**

```
Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    If (context.Session("MyFile")) IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim storedImage = TryCast(context.Session("MyFile"), Byte())
        If storedImage IsNot Nothing Then
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg"
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(storedImage)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: tried it out and I got a `System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled by user code` `Cannot access a closed file.` on `image As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)` when trying to preview for the 1st time

Comment: I created two new pages and copied the `preview_btn_click` codes and `handler1.ashx` codes you posted over and still encounter the same issue.

Comment: You can download the test project and compared with yours. Or you can email your project so that I can look at it.

Comment: I think I might have found the problem but not the solution. I tried using different images to test it out and some works and others don't. All the images are `.jpg` and only the images that are below 50KB works. Weird...

Comment: @j_t_fusion - Ok, I have updated the source with the fix for larger images. Also added a link to my test project.